# Conditional Mapping for Target

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to write Protocol Buffer (gRPC) mappings.

I have a class structure as follows

```java
public abstract class A;
public class B extends A;
public class C extends A;

public class Source {
    A a1;
    A a2;
}
```

and I have a proto file that says:

```
message Target {
  oneOf {
    B b1 = 1;
    C c1 = 2;
  }
  oneOf {
    B b2 = 3;
    C c2 = 4;
  }
}
```

AKA, proto has two VALID fields, but four real fiels, source has only two fields. And types are complicated. Mapstruct will not understand based on type signature what I want, I need to help it with some qualifiers.

I also have it set so that any un-mapped target property is an error.

This leads me to an awkward situation. As far as I understand, mapstruct has ONLY source conditioning. Only a presence check, I can't make it a "whatever I want check".

In an ideal world, I would simply write:

```java
@Mapping(target = "b1", source = "a1", qualifiedByName = "isB")
@Mapping(target = "c1", source = "a1", qualifiedByName = "isC")
@Mapping(target = "b2", source = "a2", qualifiedByName = "isB")
@Mapping(target = "c2", source = "a2", qualifiedByName = "isC")
Target toProto(Source source);

@Condition
@Named("isB")
default boolean hasB(A a) {
    return (a instanceof B);
}

@Condition
@Named("isC")
default boolean hasC(A a) {
    return (a instanceof C);
}
```

What I want to generate as code:

```java
if (hasB(source.a1) { b1 = source.a1; }
if (hasC(source.a1) { c1 = source.a1; } 
if (hasB(source.a2) { b2 = source.a2; }
if (hasC(source.a2) { c2 = source.a2; }
```

Which seems to be what a source check would generate any way. But I can't get it to do what I want it to do.

I can't leave it without the name qualifier, it can't know without it.
I have no idea how to name match.
It's giving an error on the qualifier.

If I understand correctly, I can't write `hasB1` or `hasC1`. It has to be `hasXXX` where `XXX = source property`. That does not work in this scenario, it would HAVE to be `hasYYY` where `YYY = target property`. Only other alternative is qualifiers. Qualifiers aren't working. I'm stuck.

What other options do I have? An after mapping, how would that look?

Don't forget, the `Target` is a gRpc class, the parameter would be a builder, for an after mapping. But I don't know how I'd write it.

## EDIT

Also, B, and C types are GRPC types, thus they will be mapped with another mapper added in the mapping class with "uses = {...}"

I would rather, if possible, let mapstruct do it's thing, rather than convert the mapper into an abstract, autowire the mappers and do it myself.

But if this could be done with either an `@AfterMapping` or another way with a qualifier ... then sure, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of the `qualifiedByName` is for mapping methods. What you are looking for is `conditionQualifiedByName` for the `isB` and `isC` methods.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(uses = {...})
public interface MyMapper {


    @Mapping(target = "b1", source = "a1", conditionQualifiedByName = "isB")
    @Mapping(target = "c1", source = "a1", conditionQualifiedByName = "isC")
    @Mapping(target = "b2", source = "a2", conditionQualifiedByName = "isB")
    @Mapping(target = "c2", source = "a2", conditionQualifiedByName = "isC")
    Target toProto(Source source);

    @Condition
    @Named("isB")
    default boolean hasB(A a) {
        return (a instanceof B);
    }

    @Condition
    @Named("isC")
    default boolean hasC(A a) {
        return (a instanceof C);
    }
}
```

Note: In your other mappers there should be methods that will allow you to map `A` to `B` and `A` to `C`

Note 2: The name of the presence methods are entirely up to you. The pattern `hasXXX` is only for presence methods that are present in the type itself. e.g. in this has if `Source` had a presence method `hasA1` that would check if `a1` is present or not.

Comment: Yep, this worked. The real code was considerably more complex. I had to extract fields form the source param, added them as `@Context`. Needed special methods for mapping `B` and `C` because they needed said context. Used `qualifiedBy` and `conditionQualifiedBy` to link to the methods of the helper class. But it worked like a charm!