# MapStruct @SubclassMapping by discriminator field

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am creating a MapStruct mapper from my Entity class to API Resource class that is designed by a open standard OSDM and I must adhere to its specification.

I have an entity `Leg` with discriminator property `LegType type`.

However, target `TripLeg` class looks like this:

```java
public class TripLeg {
  private TimedLeg timedLeg;
  private TransferLeg transferLeg;
  public ContinuousLeg continuousLeg;
}
```

My goal is to populate one of the fields based on `Leg.type` value.

However, `@SubclassMapping` does not take any distriminator field or expression.

I have found only solution to decorate the LegMapper and write custom logic that acts based on discriminator property and selects on of three leg subclass mappers.

Is there a declarative way to achieve this? Mapping in opposite direction is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only after posting the question and looking for more related aswers I have found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419752/conditional-mapping-for-target). Mapping property `conditionQualifiedByName` and named condition method are the solution.

```java
@Mapper
public interface LegMapper {
    @Condition
    @Named("TimedLeg")
    default boolean isTimedLeg(Leg leg) {
        return leg != null && leg.getLegType().equals("TransitLeg");
    }

    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "timedLeg", conditionQualifiedByName = "TimedLeg")
    TripLeg toResource(Leg);
}
```